# Changing Power Plans using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-ise

I am trying to create a script which switches between power plans. Here is the script:

```
$PP1 = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_PowerPlan |
           where {$_.elementname -eq "Balanced"}
$PP2 = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_PowerPlan |
       where {$_.elementname -eq "My Custom Plan 1"}

if ($PP1) {
    $PP2.Activate()
}
if ($PP2) {
    $PP1.Activate()
}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Exception calling "Activate" : "This method is not implemented in any class "
At line:6 char:1
+ $PP2.Activate()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException

Exception calling "Activate" : "This method is not implemented in any class "
At line:10 char:1
+ $PP1.Activate()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Below is the output I get after executing `$PP1`. The output is identical as `$PP2`:

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_PowerPlan
__SUPERCLASS     : CIM_SettingData
__DYNASTY        : CIM_ManagedElement
__RELPATH        : Win32_PowerPlan.InstanceID="Microsoft:PowerPlan\\{381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e}"
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 5
__DERIVATION     : {CIM_SettingData, CIM_ManagedElement}
__SERVER         : PCLP2
__NAMESPACE      : root\cimv2\power
__PATH           : \\PCLP2\root\cimv2\power:Win32_PowerPlan.InstanceID="Microsoft:PowerPlan\\{381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
                   }"
Caption          : 
Description      : Automatically balances performance with energy consumption on capable hardware.
ElementName      : Balanced
InstanceID       : Microsoft:PowerPlan\{381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e}
IsActive         : True
PSComputerName   : PCLP2
```

My goal is to add the script to Task Scheduler and every time I lock the Computer the power state switches accordingly.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Did you check that `$PP1` and `$PP2` have the values you expected?

Comment: I edited the question above showing the values I get after `PP1` and `$PP2`

Comment: Do you see a method `Activate()` when you do `$PP1 | Get-Member`? What is the actual type of your objects?

Comment: Yes, sorry but I"m not sure what do you mean by "What is the actual type of your objects?" but I get Method "Activate" under MemberType

Comment: The object type is displayed at the very top of the `Get-Member` output. The line starting with `TypeName:`. Anyway, if you do see a method `Activate` but still get the error you described then something else is amiss. Try starting a clean PowerShell console by running `powershell.exe -NoExit -NoProfile` from a CMD window or the Run dialog. Are you still getting the error when running your code in that console?

Comment: Ah I see, I tried a new console but I am getting an unusual error, `Get-WmiObject :
At line:1 char:8
+ $PP1 = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_PowerPl ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand` ,Not sure what this is

Answer (score 0):

**I think you have something to do with this code**

```
$PP1 = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Filter "ElementName ='Balanced'"
$PP2 = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Filter "ElementName = 'Power saver'"
if ($PP1.IsActive -eq "true"){
write-host Balanced
$PP2.Activate()
}
else{
Write-Host Power saver
}
```

**good luck**

Comment: Still get `Exception calling "Activate" : "This method is not implemented in any class "` Error, I'm trying to find out why I keep getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this method doesn't work on Windows 10 for some reason which I don't know exactly why, so I just worked this by using the `powercfg` command, Here is a working script.

```
$PP1 = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class win32_powerplan | where {$_.elementname -eq "Balanced"}


if ($PP1.IsActive -eq "False") {
powercfg /setactive 47f02214-4297-464e-8b31-f95e26d28082 
} Else { 

powercfg /setactive 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
}
```

Since I only have 2 power plans this is easier and simpler that's why I have 1 variable and it can only be PowerPlan A or PowerPlan B.

Not sure how to make this work on Task Scheduler because it opens a notepad for me if I run the task, though I could just make this work using bat file with the `powercfg` command, but just curious.
any way to make this work?